# How can I replace (overwrite the entire file) a sqlite database provided by SQLiteAssetHelper?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, updates, assets

I have a database file in my app's `src/main/assets/databases` directory. I want to download a new copy of the entire database (no data needs to be retained), and overwrite the old one. How can I do this with `SQLiteAssetHelper`?

My understanding is that `SQLiteAssetHelper` checks if the database is "installed" on the device, and if not, pulls it out of the `src/main/assets/databases` directory and copies it somewhere that android can use. Since I can't modify my app's assets, where does `SQLiteAssetHelper` copy the database, and what's the proper way to overwrite it?

Here's my extended `SQLiteAssetHelper`, in case it's of any use:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

public class EnumDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "enums.sqlite3";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public EnumDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I do this with SQLiteAssetHelper?

Delete the old database, then call `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWriteableDatabase()` on your `SQLiteAssetHelper`. You can call `deleteDatabase()` on any handy `Context` to delete the existing database. Make sure your database is closed first, though.

Comment: I may not have been clear. I want to download a new database file from a URL (that part I know how to do), but once I have the new file, how do I overwrite the database? I don't want to overwrite using the database that already exists in the `assets` folder.

Comment: @BLuFeNiX: Use `getDatabasePath()` to figure out where to write it, and write it there. `SQLiteAssetHelper` will have nothing to do with this process.

Comment: @CommonsWare, If we are using a ContentProvider, how would we close our database?

Comment: @hitch.united: Usually, you never close the database managed by a `ContentProvider`, as you rarely know when the right time is to do so.

Comment: @CommonsWare, FWIW, I ended up making a static method inside my content provider class to close my SQLiteDatabase object, and added checks inside the methods to re-open if necessary. Seems to be working well so far.

Comment: For those of you using ORMLite, you have to set your `DatabaseHelper` singleton to null and get a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the file path to your db file and overwrite it with another file in storage.

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "wl.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  
    public String databasePath = "";    

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        databasePath = context.getDatabasePath("wl.db").getPath();
    }
```

...

```
String toPath = db.databasePath;
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() != null) {
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyAppFolder");
    String fromPath = dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/wl.db";
    fileCopy(new File(fromPath), new File(toPath));
}


public void fileCopy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    out.flush();
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```